# calling [tableView reloadData] reverts frame change

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIView` inside a `UIViewController` in my app.

Above the `UITableView`, I have a `UISearchBar` that filters the `UITableView`. I do not want to use the conventional `UISearchBar` as it is a very custom app.

I am subscribing to notifications for when the keyboard appears and disappears, and I am resizing the `UITableView` accordingly. The problem I am having is as soon as I search, and filter the `UITableView`, I call:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

to display the filtered results only. The problem is, **the UITableView resizes itself back to its original height**, thus hiding a few cells behind the keyboard still.

Can anyone clue me in on how to change this behavior?

Comment: You sure it's a height change and not position change?

Comment: I'm thinking its just resetting back to its original constraints as supplied in the storyboard, so it is probably doing more then just changing the height, but for all intents and purposes, thats all I'm seeing

Comment: When you reload your table, do you hide the keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it might be an auto layout problem -- these often show up after some action causes the view to redraw itself. If you're using auto layout, you should resize the table view (or its containing view) by adjusting the constraints, not by setting the frame. One way to do that is to make an IBOutlet to the constraint to the bottom of the view, and modify its constant in code.

Answer (score 0):

To Debug this, I would create a subclass of `UITableView`, and override the `setBounds:` method to see who is modifying it. Once you understand and can fix the problem, you can just throw away your UITableView subclass and go back to using the normal thing.

```
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    // Break point here and inspect stack
    [super setBounds:bounds];
}
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question, should be a comment.

Comment: @Mar0ux, sorry about that. There is no way to post code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem -- not related to the keyboard, but I was attempting to resize the table and reload the table data on the same event.

What seems to work is putting a call to the table resizing method inside of `tableCell:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For efficiency, I've also given the ViewContoller a `BOOL` regarding whether the table has already been repositioned so that the table isn't repositioned for every single cell that appears.